# Using FiltersUnitTestCase to unit test Shiro security filters, IllegalStateException

Tags: unit-testing, grails, shiro

**Update**: I have changed this question to be about the specific problem I am having. This is because unit testing of Filters will be supported in Grails 2.0 so hopefully the documentation will be better then.

I am trying to write unit tests for the filters I set up to implement Shiro security in my grails app. I am using Grails 1.3.7 and wont be able to use 2.0 for a while (if ever) for this particular project.

The idea behind my filter is that I need to give anonymous access to a number or controller/action combinations but protect access to the others. I also want it to fail safe, i.e. if you forget to explicitly allow access then access is prohibited.

**The filter class**

```
class SecurityFilters {
    def filters = {

        homeAccess(controller: "home", action: "*") {
            before = {

                // Allow all access
                request.accessAllowed = true
            }
        }

        serverAccess(controller: "server", action: "list") {
            before = {

                // Allow all access
                request.accessAllowed = true
            }
        }

        layerAccess(controller: "layer", action: "list|listBaseLayersAsJson|listNonBaseLayerAsJson|showLayerByItsId") {
            before = {

                // Allow all access
                request.accessAllowed = true
            }
        }

        all(uri: "/**") {
            before = {

                // Check if request has been allowed by another filter
                if (request.accessAllowed) return true            

                // Ignore direct views (e.g. the default main index page).
                if (!controllerName) return true

                // Access control by convention.
                accessControl(auth: false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The Unit tests**

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.filters.FilterConfig

class SecurityFiltersTests extends FiltersUnitTestCase {

    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testHomeControllerFilter() {

        checkFilter('homeAccess')
    }

    void testServerControllerFilter() {

        checkFilter('serverAccess')
    }

    void testLayerControllerFilter() {

        checkFilter('layerAccess')
    }

    void testAllFilter() {

        assertTrue "Write tests", false
    }

    void checkFilter(String filterName) {

        FilterConfig filter = initFilter(filterName)
        assertNotNull filterName + " filter should exist", filter
        assertExistsBefore(filterName)

        assertEquals "accessAllowed should be null to start with", null, filter.request.accessAllowed

        // Run filter
        filter.before()

        assertEquals "accessAllowed should be true now", true, filter.request.accessAllowed
    }
}
```

**The Exception**

The problem is that when these test are run I get the following exception:

```
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at grails.test.MockUtils$_addCommonWebProperties_closure32.doCall(MockUtils.groovy:316)
    at shiro.SecurityFilters$_closure1_closure5_closure12.doCall(SecurityFilters.groovy:40)
    at shiro.SecurityFilters$_closure1_closure5_closure12.doCall(SecurityFilters.groovy)
    at shiro.SecurityFiltersTests.checkFilter(SecurityFiltersTests.groovy:92)
    at shiro.SecurityFiltersTests$checkFilter.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at shiro.SecurityFiltersTests.testLayerControllerFilter(SecurityFiltersTests.groovy:65)
```

Additionally I have placed the following line in the Unit test:

```
println "filter.request: " + filter.request
```

Which prints the following:

```
filter.request: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockHttpServletRequest@2914cca4
```

So it certainly seems to be using a mock request object.

So, the questions.

**Am I using FiltersUnitTestCase correctly to execute my filters?**

And, if so:

**Why am I experiencing this exception?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reminder to the rules of debugging for everyone out there: **Keep removing code until you find the exact line the problem is on. Even if it is obvious that the line is not causing the problem.** Because: *sometimes it actually is*.

As part of my debugging work I had the following line of code in my filter:

```
println "controllerName = '${controllerName}', actionName = '${actionName}'"
```

This was directly before the line:

```
request.accessAllowed = true
```

I had taken it out of the code pasted into this question to try and keep it tidy, but apparently I hadn't tried commenting it out when running the tests. Sorry to anyone who looked-into that code and couldn't find a problem. You were right, the problem wasn't in any of the code I provided.

So the answer is **you may see the exception reported here if you try and access the `controllerName` or `actionName` variables**.

The solution is to use the `setControllerName()` and `setActionName()` methods in FiltersUnitTestCase before executing any filter that might reference `controllerName` or `actionName`.